# Remove ReactJs function in mobile view

Tags: reactjs, responsive-design

Assume I have a component with two functions that are run when the app is launched. If I switch the app to responsive width and that width is mobile, I only want one function to run and the second one must be removed.

Is there anyone who can assist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get window width and set `if` statement.

```
const width = window.innerWidth

if (width === 400) {
  runFunction()
}
```

or

```
const width = window.innerWidth

const runFunction = () => {
  if (width === 400) {
    // ...function logic
    return
  }
   
  return
}
```